# Membership operators in C

Tags: c

I have this assignment that I am trying to finish, although it makes no benefite for my grades.

The assignment is Zonk game, this game includes 6 dice rolling. So Everything is ready except the scoring part. I have 6 dices that I need to look insind of them to detect a pattern that will give a score either to the user or to the computer.

So the solution I reached works only for the case where the pattern is organized, such as 555-423 or 423-555, if theirs any 3 numbers appeared in a row it will count the score for them. So if theirs a 1 and two 5s in the set in such a way 123-565, I can't detect them, I will need a different way to analyze the result of rolling the dice.

While I was revising Python, I remembered the membership operators (in-not in).*Is there anything similar to the membership operators that exists in Python and that can help me solve my problem in C?* this might help solve the problem.

```
if(d1==6&&d2==6&&d3==6){
 }
 else if(d1==6&&d2==6&&d3==1){
 }
 else if(d1==6&&d2==1&&d3==6){
 }
```

and my code continues like that for all numbers.

```
 else if(d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6==21){
 }
 else{
    if((d4+d5+d6)==3){                      //1-1-1
        returnscore+= 1000;
    }
    else if(d4==6){                         //6-6-6
        if(d5==6){
            if(d6==6){                      //this part should have &&
                returnscore= 600;
            }
```

at the else part I check for pattern at the last three dices.

**Important Note**: I am not allowed to use arrays!

Comment: "membership operators that exists in Python" is irrelevant since "I am not allowed to use arrays!" (thats just stubborn) . "Zonk game" ... as there are many variations of that game it would be necessary that you spezifie how exaktly scoring works.

Comment: "I am not allowed to..." -- One of these days I will be going on a rampage and slap all these instructors with their course material until they renounce their evil "do this with one hand strapped to your back" ways.

Comment: You could sort the values on the dice so that they are in rising (or falling) sequence.  That should make analysis easier. The ridiculous “no arrays” rule makes life unnecessarily difficult. One can only hope that the next exercise is “do it with arrays; notice how much easier it is with the correct tools”.  I’m not confident that’s what will happen though. Are structures allowed?

Comment: no advanced topics such as structures are allowed. Including arrayes. Basically normal operators and dicision making with loops. thats all

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will try to sort it, I have done it already to match the output. From the first glance I believe I could include it in the roll_a_dice() function

Comment: I'm sorry you are suffering under such rigid rules.  If you're comfortable with arrays, maybe you should program an array solution and make that work.  Then rework to meet the ridiculous homework requirements.  I'm really not sure what you're meant to learn from this other than the fact that basic data structures like arrays and structs make life easier than simple variables.

Comment: My classmate is doing it in structs, he has it on Github github.com/Timbwa/Zonk-Game  I will also try to improve it in the future to make my self comfortable with arrays. Thanks for you engagement. Please do me a +1. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @DevSolar I do see it as unnecessary as well to make us suffer. But really if they make it as a SummerWork who would mind him self solving it. And at the end they will reach second year courses of Data Structurs and OOP and they will fail badly. Instead of failing in the middle of the journey, they make us fail at the begging to make the gear works hard from the begging of the journey.

Comment: How about writing two functions `get(int)` and `set(int,int)` that just have a big switch statement to get/set the appropriate global variable. Then you can program exactly as if you had an array, while using neither arrays nor pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the scoring rules but:

```
if(d1 == d2 && d2 == d3)   //all in the row
{
    switch(d1)
    {
        case 1:    //all ones
            resultscore =...
            break;
        case 2:    //all 2
            resultscore =...
            break;
        case 3:    //all 3
            resultscore =...
            break;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problems solution isn't going to be membership operators even if it exists in `C`, As the brothers mentioned if arrays arn't allowed it will be useless to have such an operators.

In this case the only way to solve the problem is through sorting the dices once rolled. Ofcourse pointers aren't allowed, So you can't do it from within `roll_a_dice()` function. Hence you will do it in `play_computer` and `play_user` functions. of course thanks to @Jonathan Leffler --up in the comments-- for the idea.

Solved this, now time to ask another question regarding debugging in order to test each part separately.LOL.

Comment: imagine no pass by reference

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that sorts the values in 6 simple variables (no structures, no arrays).  My preferred version uses pointers and a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int test_and_swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    if (*p1 > *p2)
    {
        int t = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = t;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int v1 = 93;
    int v2 = 81;
    int v3 = 63;
    int v4 = 84;
    int v5 = 14;
    int v6 = 87;

    int swap;

    printf("v1 = %d; v2 = %d; v3 = %d; v4 = %d; v5 = %d; v6 = %d\n",
           v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
    do
    {
        swap = 0;
        swap += test_and_swap(&v1, &v2);
        swap += test_and_swap(&v2, &v3);
        swap += test_and_swap(&v3, &v4);
        swap += test_and_swap(&v4, &v5);
        swap += test_and_swap(&v5, &v6);
    } while (swap != 0);
    printf("v1 = %d; v2 = %d; v3 = %d; v4 = %d; v5 = %d; v6 = %d\n",
           v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
v1 = 93; v2 = 81; v3 = 63; v4 = 84; v5 = 14; v6 = 87
v1 = 14; v2 = 63; v3 = 81; v4 = 84; v5 = 87; v6 = 93
```

A version which doesn't use pointers even doesn't use a function but does use repetitive coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int v1 = 93;
    int v2 = 81;
    int v3 = 63;
    int v4 = 84;
    int v5 = 14;
    int v6 = 87;

    int swap;

    printf("v1 = %d; v2 = %d; v3 = %d; v4 = %d; v5 = %d; v6 = %d\n",
           v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
    do
    {
        swap = 0;
        if (v1 > v2) { int t = v1; v1 = v2; v2 = t; swap = 1; }
        if (v2 > v3) { int t = v2; v2 = v3; v3 = t; swap = 1; }
        if (v3 > v4) { int t = v3; v3 = v4; v4 = t; swap = 1; }
        if (v4 > v5) { int t = v4; v4 = v5; v5 = t; swap = 1; }
        if (v5 > v6) { int t = v5; v5 = v6; v6 = t; swap = 1; }
    } while (swap != 0);

    printf("v1 = %d; v2 = %d; v3 = %d; v4 = %d; v5 = %d; v6 = %d\n",
           v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same, of course.

I stand by my contention (made in comments) that the exercise is imposing ridiculous limits on your programming.  This is not code that should be used in production — the requirements imposed on the solution are not sensible.